# Importing data in mysql without overwriting some columns

Tags: mysql

Ok, i have been sitting on this problem for a while, i found some workarounds but i want to know if it is possible to do it the way i thought.

I have 2 databases, one remote (i will call it `DB_A`) on a webserver collecting data and one on my local machine analyzing this data (i will call it `DB_B`).The tables have basically the same structure but on the processing side (`DB_B`) i added some columns.

So the server side(`DB_A`) looks something like this:

```
|UserID|LastActive|InfoA|InfoB|
```

and on the local side (`DB_B`) like this:

```
|UserID|LastActive|InfoA|InfoB|InfoC|
```

So when i initially import the data to my local side `InfoC` is `NULL` and i then process the data to have something useful in `InfoC`. In the meantime the `DB_A` is filled and updated with new data. 
What i want is to export the Data from `DB_A` and import it into `DB_B` with updating the fields like `LastActive` and `InfoB` without overwriting `InfoC` so i can later process all the rows that dont have `InfoC` set yet

What i have found so far:

- A simple mysqldump and import doesnt work because the structure of the tables is different. Therefore i use a mysql with the  --execute and -X parameter to get a XML datafile
- Importing the XML file on `DB_B` works without errors when i use: 
  `LOAD XML INFILE 'path/to/file.xml' REPLACE INTO TABLE users;` but it clears all information in `InfoC`
- When i use the `INSERT IGNORE` statement instead it obviously doesn't update the already imported users.

So my question is: is there a way to do this wit MySQL withhout using  workarounds like an intermediate table.

Addition: I know this can easily be done with the use of PHP or any other langugage but i want to stick to a, hopefully, simple MySQL solution

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Simon I got a fairly simple solution which uses a tmp database. with this i can even use mysqldump and dont need to use the slow XML-way:

```
# create temporary db (for tweaking performance create it in memory)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users;
CREATE TABLE tmp_users LIKE users; 

# import data (just as an example, this is not mysql syntax)
mysql<users.sql

# this is even simpler than in the answer
# since you don't have to specify values for the select and insert
INSERT INTO users
SELECT * FROM tmp_users
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  LastActive = VALUES(LastActive),
  InfoA = VALUES(InfoA),
  InfoB = VALUES(InfoB);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an INSERT is probably the way to do this, something along the lines of the following, making use of "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" (link to docs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html )

```
-- Set up the insert into DB_B
INSERT INTO DB_B (
  UserID, -- Assuming this is the PK
  LastActive,
  InfoA,
  InfoB,
  InfoC
) 
-- Do whatever you did in your INSERT IGNORE statement, a temp. table is probably most efficient though
SELECT
  UserID,
  LastActive,
  InfoA,
  InfoB,
  NULL -- Assumes that the default for InfoC is NULL
FROM tempTable
-- Now tell MySQL to update any where the PK matches
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  LastActive = VALUES(LastActive),
  InfoA = VALUES(InfoA),
  InfoB = VALUES(InfoB)
```

I cannot really see a way to do this straight-up with the LOAD DATA alone though due to the fact that it only really seems to support `IGNORE` and `REPLACE` as options, neither of which really suits your purposes.

Comment: thanks for the answer but for this i would have to import the data into a temporary table first. is there a way to do this directly from a mysqldum or xml file?

Comment: Not easily.  Your key problem is that you are not able to REPLACE or IGNORE the clashing PKs as there is data within the target table that is not present within the source table. You could though work this into a simple procedure which just makes a temporary table in memory, loads in the data, runs the INSERT, and then drops the temporary table.  This is probably the simplest method you'll find, and will at least mean it's entirely within MySQL instead of having to do a patch of selects/inserts PHP etc

Comment: ok, thanks! i will have a look at this and report back as soon as i got something

Comment: ok, looked at it and wrote a procedure that does this. thanks a lot! i will accept your answer and post the completed script the question, i think this is preferred over writing another answer.